# File Provider Extension for macOS is missing in Xcode 11

Tags: xcode11, macos-catalina, fileprovider-extension

**Update:**
I found that File Provider Extension API is removed from [Catalina features page](https://www.apple.com/macos/catalina/features/). Is that mean this feature won't be available on macOS Catalina?

---

I upgraded Xcode to Xcode 11 GM2(11A420a) on macOS Catalina beta.8. Then I tried to create an application extension by clicking `File > New > Target` and found that File Provider extension is missing from the application extension list for macOS.

I remembered I could create a File Provider extension for macOS in a previous beta version of Xcode 11. What to do now?

Comment: That's a shame, I was really looking forward to using this API. There's nothing mentioned in the release notes, either.